# add Logo in kml file

Tags: c#, kml

I want to add my company logo in kml file using c#.

I have tried a lot of things but nothing works.

Please help me out thanks in advance.

Comment: show what you've tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376320/writing-a-kml-using-c-sharp-screenoverlay?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

To add your logo to the KML you can add a [ScreenOverlay](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#screenoverlay) to the KML.

The screen overlay defines an image that always appears at a fixed position on the screen that does not change when you change location or zoom in/out. The imagery overlay, on the other hand, is fixed to a location on the map that moves as the view changes.

To make a logo appear in the lower-left of the map add this to your KML:

```
 <ScreenOverlay>
    <name>Logo</name>   
    <description>Screen overlay Example</description>
    <Icon>
      <href>http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif</href>
    </Icon> 
    <!-- put image at the left-corner of the image -->
    <overlayXY x="0" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
    <screenXY x="5" y="5" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels" />    
  </ScreenOverlay>
```

The `<overlayXY>` element defines an point in the image and the `<screenXY>`
defines an anchor point on the map that the overlay image is anchored to. The points in the overlay can be defined in either pixel coordinate system or a fractional-coordinate system.

First get the KML to the way you want it to appear in Google Earth then make the changes to your C# code to generate it.

For a real-world example of a logo in KML see the USGS Earthquake KML
http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_month_age_link.kml

Comment: string strdocA = Server.MapPath("~/Document/KML/doc.kml");
        string strdocB = Server.MapPath("~/Document/KML/MaxConLOGOnew.kml");
        string strdocC = Server.MapPath("~/Document/KML/vvkml");

Comment: XmlTextWriter kml = new XmlTextWriter(path, null);
  kml.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
  kml.WriteStartElement("kml", strdocA);
  kml.WriteStartElement("ScreenOverlay");
  kml.WriteElementString("name", "elephant");
  kml.WriteStartElement("Icon");
  kml.WriteElementString("href", "images/elephant.jpg");
  kml.WriteEndElement();

Comment: kml.WriteStartElement("overlayXY");    
  kml.WriteAttributeString("x", "0");
  kml.WriteAttributeString("y", "1");
  kml.WriteAttributeString("xunits", "fraction");
  kml.WriteAttributeString("yunits", "fraction");
  kml.WriteEndElement();

Comment: kml.WriteStartElement("screenXY");
  kml.WriteAttributeString("x", "0");
  kml.WriteAttributeString("y", "0");
  kml.WriteAttributeString("xunits", "pixels");
  kml.WriteAttributeString("yunits", "pixels");
  kml.WriteEndElement();
  kml.WriteEndElement();
  kml.WriteEndElement();

Comment: i tried above code could plz tell me what is wrong here in my code

Comment: What is the error and/or what is the output of the KML file that is wrong? Can you manually add the SceenOverlay to the existing KML file?

Comment: actually i am taking kml file where it is stored then trying to add my company logo in that kml using c#. complete process i mentioned above. is there any other way to do this...